# How does the link determine what addresses need to be edited?

Tags: computer-science

I am reading my textbook and I see this passage:

[image]

[image]

How do we know that the `jal` instruction in procedure A needs an address that refers to one in procedure B? How do we know it's not an address in procedure A? What in the object file for procedure A tells us that?

The `sw` makes sense to me: I can see why the 0 is replaced by an 8000 in procecure A's lw instruction: the `$gp` is at `10008000hex` and so the 8000 is relative to 10000000, which is the base address. But the jal instruction is a bit unclear. Like... how do we know it's supposed to reference an address in the other procedure?